# VSCode, Github, New Project, Cloned Repo: How do you use all these without taking manual steps?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

VSCode has it's buttons for new project, can even make it push to github.
Or you can clone from a github repo to a new local project dir.

But those require manual steps.

What is the vscode command to encapsulate all of this?

Clone an existing repo
***and*** create a new local git project
***and*** create a github repo

Comment: Can you not do this using git commands?

Comment: @Saikat: Creating a repo on GitHub requires using the GitHub APIs. There is a [`gh` command line package](https://github.com/cli/cli) from the GitHub folks. (Note that while this is a Git repository on GitHub, which stores Git repositories, none of this has anything to do with Git itself, except that they use it and make Git repos. So the relationship to Git is ... intentional, yet tenuous? I'm not sure what to call it...)

Comment: @Saikat The question, as clearly stated, is about VSCode.

Comment: @monsto in that case, one option could be to use the `gh-cli` as suggested by @torek and then create a bash function with the required steps. Not sure if any such VSCode extension exists.